# Order files based on a given priority - lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I have n files of this type:

```
file_A.xml
file_2.xml
file_Z.xml
```

I need to take the file with highest priority. The priority is defined following this rule

```
A to Z, then 1 to 5
```

being 5 the maximum priority and A the lowest priority.

Do you have any suggestion to do it? I can use Java 8 so it would be ideal if I could use a lambda expression but I am not very strong with them.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Comparator` to sort the `List` of files.

Your actual order :

> A to Z, then 1 to 5

doesn't rely on a lexicographical order (order used for the `Comparable` implementation of `String`)

Your requirement makes indeed appear alphabetical characters before numeric characters while the lexicographical order does the reverse.
 
But between two characters of same nature (alphabet or numeric), you use a lexicographical order.

As a consequence, you have to perform `String` manipulations to determinate the order between two `String`s.
In this way, you could not really take advantage of Java 8.
If the sort relies on direct field comparison, you could have done it.

So, you could write a `Comparator` :

```
Comparator<String> priorityFileComparator = Comparator.comparing(
    String::toString, (s1, s2) -> {         
        char s1Priority = s1.substring(5, 6).charAt(0);
        char s2Priority = s2.substring(5, 6).charAt(0);

        if (Character.isAlphabetic(s1Priority) && !Character.isAlphabetic(s2Priority)){
          return -1;            
        }

        if (Character.isAlphabetic(s2Priority) && !Character.isAlphabetic(s1Priority)){
          return 1;
        }

        return s1.compareTo(s2); // same nature -> lexicographical comparison
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need lambdas for this. If you have your files in a `List<File>` then just use

```
Collections.sort(fileList, new Comparator<File>() {
  public int compare(File f1, File f2){
    // do your complex order logic here
  }
});
```

You may do it with Lambdas, I guess, but if you have complex logic to sort, then you need a distinct Comparator anyway. And streaming the collection afaik is more costly than using the Collections class as described above.

Hope this helps, Patrick